# Salesforce setting fiscal year

Tags: setup, custom-fiscal-year

I am trying to restructure our fiscal year to 4-4-5 to be in-line with our accounting month end dates. Our weeks begin on Saturday and the first month of 2014 will run from Dec 28 (2013) thru Jan 24, the second month Jan 25 thru Feb 21. On the preview, the months are shown as first month "December" and second month "January". We want the first month to be listed as January, second month February and so on. Is it possible to rename these months? If so, how? Any help that you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't. Month or week periods cannot be defined beyond standards.

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange. When posting questions please try to select tags related to the subject of your question, that will help attract users with the right knowledge. I've taken the liberty to update your question for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

I think that custom fiscal year settings allow you to define any day as a start day for the period, and you actually could modify periods created from 4-4-5 (or any other) template.
That's actually what we are trying to implement - to have a **fiscal year starting on Oct-16** and all monthly periods on 16th day of each month.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that any of the fiscal year options, including custom fiscal years, allow for a mid-month start/end date, nor a change to month labels.